# C# .NET: read method of OleDbDataReader class won't run

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, forms, ms-access-2013

I am building an intranet for my school project inside a form application using the .NET framework and the C# language. This function populates a data grid inside a form. However, the code inside the while structure won't run. I have gone step by step with the debugger, and I reckon the read() method of the "dr" object will not go trough my two inner joined tables, but when I press a button that i have set to show me how many books are there registered in the database, it works. I think there is something wrong with my SQL statement, by what I have searched on this site, but I did not manage to resolve the bug. Carti.Nota and Carti.Stoc are columns with the Number type inside a Microsoft Access 2013 Database.

```
private void PopulateGridBooks()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibrarieConectare"].ConnectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titlu", cautaTitlu.Text);
            command.CommandText =
                 " SELECT Carti.IDCarte, Carti.Titlu, Carti.Editie, Carti.An, Carti.ISBN, Carti.Nota, Carti.IDAutor, Carti.Stoc, Edituri.NumeEditura " +
                 " FROM (Carti INNER JOIN Edituri ON Carti.IDEditura = Edituri.IDEditura) " +
                 " WHERE Titlu LIKE '%@titlu%'";
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr["IDCarte"], dr["Titlu"], dr["NumeEditura"], dr["Stoc"]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Eroare la populare data grid carti: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the code as a text, not as a linked picture.

Comment: what are getting as output?

Comment: From a quick look, the ( ) are not required around the join. What happens if you get the query text from the command text during debugging and paste it in to query analyzer? Does it return results? Also, move your dr.Read() above the while and set it as a variable. e.g. var x = dr.Read() and then inspect the value of x in the debugger to help understand where it is going wrong. Lastly, are you getting anything in the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I found it - your parameter is wrong, you should not have an @ in the AddwithValue.

Use:

```
//Exclude the @ in the below. 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("titlu", cautaTitlu.Text);
```

maybe move your parameter addition line to after the command text too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 command.CommandText =
                 " SELECT Carti.IDCarte, Carti.Titlu, Carti.Editie, Carti.An, Carti.ISBN, Carti.Nota, Carti.IDAutor, Carti.Stoc, Edituri.NumeEditura " +
                 " FROM Carti INNER JOIN Edituri ON Carti.IDEditura = Edituri.IDEditura " +
                 " WHERE Titlu LIKE '%' + @titlu +  '%';
```

Comment: It works without the "@" for some reason, but on other version of visual studio, which my mate has, it works with the "@" too. Anyways, thanks for taking time to review my query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest change in where clause as the following:
"WHERE Titlu LIKE '%' + @titlu +  '%'"